# Ubuntu can't see (ping,ssh,Nmap) other nodes in local network

Tags: networking, ssh, ping

my local network include 3 nodes.

1- my windows 7 PC

2- raspberry pi 3 (with Libreelec)

3- my Lenovo laptop with Ubuntu (can access to internet with any problem)

in this local network, my PC can ping all nodes and also can connect to raspberry pi through SSH (with Putty). but my Ubuntu laptop can't ping neither of nodes.

ping => `From 192.168.1.6 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable`

Comment: Please, post the output of 'ifconfig' (without quotes).

Comment: ... and `ip route show` or `route`

Comment: output of 'ifconfig' => https://paste.ubuntu.ir/bqmn

Comment: this is my routing Table => https://paste.ubuntu.ir/tgto